# De Morgan's Law

Tags: java, boolean-logic, demorgans-law

I am trying to simplify the following using DeMorgan's Law: ! (x!=0 || y !=0)

Does x!=0 simplify to x>0? Or am I wrong in the following:

```
 !(x>0 || y>0)
 !(x>0) && !(y>0)
 ((x<=0) && (y<=0))
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a positive number, then yes, (x!=0) <-> (x>0). In programming you will usually handle only positive numbers. So it's usually the same depending on the problematic, although when you don't know what X is, it is **wrong**.

Comment: ! (x!=0 || y !=0), your original statement, is about as simple as it gets I suppose. Though, to properly simplify Boolean algebra you have to convert all the terms to variables, true, and false. Taking 0 as false yields !(x||y) which could be converted into a conjunction !x && !y but, since 0 actually represents a number in your statement you would have to consider != 0 somewhere else for both terms and use the Boolean results in your logical statement. For sure, when dealing with a boolean set of numbers (1 and 0) any x!=0 is x>0, though for number sets including negatives it is not true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does x!=0 simplify to x>0?

No that's not true. Because integers are signed.

---

How to simplify : 
    `!(x!=0 || y !=0)` ?

Consider this rules :

1. [image] (second [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) )
2. [image]

By 1., it implies

`!(x!=0 || y !=0) <=> (!(x!=0)) && (!(y != 0))`

By 2., it implies

`(!(x!=0)) && (!(y != 0)) <=> (x == 0) && (y == 0)`

---

To test you can write the following loop :

```
for(int x = -5; x < 5; x++){
     for(int y = -5; y < 5; y++){
         if(!(x!=0 || y !=0))
            System.out.println("True : ("+x+","+y+")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

DeMorgans Law states the following:

```
!(A & B) = !A | !B    (I)
!(A | B) = !A & !B    (II)
```

In your case `(II)` applies: `!(x!=0 || y!=0)` => `!(x!=0) && !(y!=0)` => `(x==0) && (y==0)`

**PS:** Your question: "Does x!=0 simplify to x>0?" can be answered with "no" unless x can not take negative values (for example if the type of x is unsigned).

Comment: I think, he meant replacing '!=' with '>' in the law he mentioned first.

Comment: I meant whether x!=0 equals to x>0 according to DeMorgan's law however that's not correct as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

> Does x!=0 simplify to x>0? Or am I wrong in the following:

```
x != 0  // reads x does not equal 0; any number BUT 0

x > 0 // reads x is greater than 0; only numbers greater than 0
```

Do these two look the same, when you write it out like this?

Combined

```
(x != 0 && x > 0) // any number above 0
(x != 0 || x > 0) // any number BUT 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In java integers are always signed so it is not necessarily true that x!=0 is the same as x>0

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of the first two comparisons according to De' Morgan's law is the following.

```
 !(x>0 || y>0)        --->      x <= 0 && y <= 0
```

---

```
 !(x>0) && !(y>0)     --->      !(x <=0 || y <=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I teach how to write Java **do-while** loops, I explain how to write the condition which terminates the loop.

For example, if I want to ask the user to enter a value which must be 0, 1, 2, or 3, I want the while condition to continue if the input value is not (value >= 0 and value <= 3).

This translates into while (!(value >= 0) or !(value <= 3)).

But !(value >= 0) means (value < 0), and !(value <= 3) means (value > 3), so the while loop is written as **while (value < 0 || value > 3)**.

Hope this helps.