# While loop doesn't respect both conditions

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
int lim1, lim2, nr1, nr2;
lim1=1; lim2=1;
nr1=6; nr2=7;
while (nr1 != lim1 && nr2 != lim2) 
{
    nr1--; nr2--;
    cout << nr1 << ' ' << nr2 << endl;
}
```

Why does the while stop when `nr1` gets to be 1, but `nr2` doesn't. Isn't `&&` supposed to mean that both conditions **have to be met**? `nr2` isn't 1 at the end of the loop so why doesn't it become an infinite loop?

And why is this loop working? It is an infinite loop, as expected.

```
while (!(nr1 == lim1 && nr2 == lim2)) 
{
    nr1--; nr2--;
    cout << nr1 << ' ' << nr2 << endl;
}
```

Aren't both conditions checking the same thing?

Comment: I spent the whole day yesterday trying to figure it out but I just can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [De Morgan's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043664/de-morgans-law)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, and it SHOULDN'T stop because not both numbers are 1. Only one of them is. It should go on infinitely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `nr1` is `1`, then `nr2` is `2`. So when `nr1 != lim1` is false then `nr2 != lim2` is still true, but since the whole expression is false (because the logical AND) the loop ends. That is how logical AND works, *both* expressions have to be true for the whole expression to be true.

And the two conditions you have in the different loops aren't equal. [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) says that

```
nr1 != lim1 && nr2 != lim2
```

is equal to

```
!(nr1 == lim1 || nr2 == lim2)
```

The laws also says that

```
!(nr1 == lim1 && nr2 == lim2)
```

is equal to

```
nr1 != lim1 || nr2 != lim2
```

---

You should also note that there is no "infinity" with integers. All integers are limited. The type `int` is on most systems a 32-bit signed integer, which means its range is about two billion to minus two billion. And when a signed integer over- or under-flows you will have *undefined behavior*.

So the end result of your infinite loop is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Does *undefined behavior* mean it could exit the loop, one day? :P

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Who knows? It is, after all, *undefined...* For all we know, it could even summon [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o with undefined behaviour... what loop? ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple mathematical formula, which is called De Morgan's formula, which says

[image]

In C++, [image] is denoted by !.[image] is denoted by $$, and [image] is denoted by ||. So your expression must be converted to the following form
!(nr1==lim1 || nr2==lim2) to be equvalent with (nr1!=lim1 && nr2!=lim2)

Answer (score 0):

Actually both condition do what they are supposed to do, so let's break them down.

#### First

`while(nr1!=lim1 && nr2!=lim2)` - Can be translated in english as, keep looping as long as both nr1 is different from lim1 and nr2 is different from lim2.

#### Second

`while(!(nr1==lim1&&nr2==lim2))` - Can be translated to english as, keep looping as long as nr1 and nr2 are not equal respectively to lim1 and lim2.

The code doesn't do exactly what you want because nr1 and nr2 are set to 6 and 7. This means that in the first while loop nr1 will arrive first 1 and so will break the loop. Instead for the second condition it will always evaluate to true because there is not way for nr1 and nr2 to be contemporary equal to lim1 and lim2 respectively because there is a difference of 1 between nr1 and nr2.

Answer (score 0):

```
nr1 != lim1 && nr2 != lim2
```

This statement is `true` if both:

- `nr1` is different from `lim1`
- `nr2` is different from `lim2`

So **your program will stop iterating if at least one condition isn’t met**.

---

```
nr1 == lim1 && nr2 == lim2
```

This statement is `true` only if both condtions are met. So if at least one condition isn’t met, the statement becomes `false`.

```
!(nr1 == lim1 && nr2 == lim2)
```

So now if you reverse the statement, it means it will be `true` if the statement was `false`. So with this condition, you’re telling your program: ”continue to iterate as long as at least one of the conditions is not met”. In other words, **your program will iterate until both conditions are met**.