# Java conditional - How to format simple if statement with 3 scenarios? if structure advice

Tags: java, if-statement, formatting

I'm having an issue where my code just feels messy and I need some help on how I could structure it better.

example:

```
if (object.getDescription() == Status.Expected && !logEvent.equals("Expected")) {
    System.out.println("Do nothing"); // ???
} else {
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}
```

How can i format this if in a cleaner way? I want the `changedBy` method to be called in every case except when `getDescription == Status.Expected` and `logEvent` is not `"Expected"`. But I don't want an empty if statement either.

An alternative is:

```
if (object.getDescription() == Status.Expected) {
   if (logEvent.equals("Expected")) {
         status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
   }
} else {
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}
```

Both examples work. But neither examples "feels right". Is there any other solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: If you have an `if-else` with an empty `if` like in your first example you can simply flip the conditions in the `if` (think about what the condition of the `else` really is), so you just have an `if` with no `else`.

Comment: `if (!(object.getDescription() == Status.Expected && !logEvent.equals("Expected")))`

Comment: @ScottHunter Can be simplified. !(A && !B) == !A || B

Comment: @Michael: True, but the "unsimplified" might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invert the condition by applying the `!` operator to the whole thing. Then you can put the code in the `if` block instead of the `else` block.

```
if (!(object.getDescription() == Status.Expected && !logEvent.equals("Expected"))) {
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}
```

You can further simplify this using [De Morgan's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043664/de-morgans-law):

```
if (object.getDescription() != Status.Expected || logEvent.equals("Expected")) {
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}
```

You change the status when "the description is not expected *or* `logEvent` is expected"

Comment: Or if you're lazy, just dump the expression into wolfram alpha and see what the the minimal form is. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%21%28A+AND+%21B%29

Comment: That's some black magic right there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, what you are looking for is that :

```
if (object.getDescription() != Status.Expected || logEvent.equals("Expected")) {
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}
```

I took your original comparison and reversed it.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it takes more code, but I would go for this approach:

```
if (shouldChangeStatus(object, logEvent))
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}

private boolean shouldChangeStatus(Object object, Object logEvent) {
    if (object.getDescription() != Status.Expected) {
        return true;
    }
    if (logEvent.equals("Expected")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can simplify it to something like that

```
if (shouldChangeStatus(object, logEvent))
    status.setChangedBy(logEvent);
}


private boolean shouldChangeStatus(Object object, Object logEvent) {
    if (object.getDescription() != Status.Expected) {
        return true;
    }
    return logEvent.equals("Expected");
}
```

It's the easiest way to maintain that code, also if you ever need that check in other place you can just change private to public/protected or whatever and just use it without a need to copy paste code

Answer (score 0):

Minor addition to the previous answers: it's good practice to put the constant string first in a comparison like this `"Expected".equals(logEvent)`. This way if logEvent is null, it will not throw a NPE.